# Need to learn to write by hand more neat and fast

Tags: typography, handwriting

I searched the internet for tips for writing both fast and neat for exams but only found a few tips on the internet, so I came here looking if anyone had any trade secrets they may be able to share.

If I can't achieve this VCAA (the marking agency for my final year) could deduct points from me solely on being unable to read my handwriting

I have to acquire this skill before 4 weeks are up at which time my exam period will start

Thanks for you help

Comment: I value neat over fast, because they fight each other, and neat has more value.

Comment: @YosefBaskin do you know how to implement both? Or what method do you favour for working yourself?

Comment: How are your fine motor skills in general?

Comment: Practice every day. Get a writing instrument that writes easily without too much pressure.

Comment: @Jim no different from anybody else

Comment: So start slower and visualize the shape of the letters you want to write and then form them just as you envision them. Do this over and over until the form comes naturally. Then slowly increase the speed while maintaining the desired shape.

Comment: @Jim sure I'll try to implement that overtime thanks for the recommendation

Comment: You seem to have received good advice, so it is time to close the question because it is not really about English language or usage.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has now received helpful comments but is not about English, language, or usage. It is about a manual skill.